# Failing to get django-wiki fork installed and working so I can collaborate a little bit

Tags: django-wiki

I expect I'm doing something dumb.  First time I've tried to work on a library fork.
I made a fork of django-wiki on github and I want to install it locally so I can make a tiny change to make the table alignment markdown work as it should, and maybe make a test for that.  I've had about 10 tries at this, learning a little bit each time.  I apologise for the long post but here's my latest console log:

```
C:\>md python

C:\>cd python

C:\python>python --version
Python 3.9.6

C:\python>pip --version
pip 23.3.1 from c:\users\ianpi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

C:\python>python -m venv wiki-env

C:\python>wiki-env\scripts\activate.bat

(wiki-env) C:\python>pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-4.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.6.0
  Using cached asgiref-3.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.3.1
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Collecting tzdata
  Using cached tzdata-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (341 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=4
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, tzdata, sqlparse, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.7.2 django-4.2.6 sqlparse-0.4.4 typing-extensions-4.8.0 tzdata-2023.3
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 23.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python\wiki-env\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(wiki-env) C:\python>python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python\wiki-env\lib\site-packages (21.1.3)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python\wiki-env\lib\site-packages (56.0.0)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (807 kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 56.0.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-56.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-56.0.0
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.3
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1.3
Successfully installed pip-23.3.1 setuptools-68.2.2

(wiki-env) C:\python>pip install -e git+https://github.com/yengip/django-wiki.git#egg=wiki
Obtaining wiki from git+https://github.com/yengip/django-wiki.git#egg=wiki
  Cloning https://github.com/yengip/django-wiki.git to c:\python\wiki-env\src\wiki
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/yengip/django-wiki.git 'c:\python\wiki-env\src\wiki'
  Resolved https://github.com/yengip/django-wiki.git to commit 3d12558f237f9dc0d1064e362873f6dbfbe3a576
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting bleach<7,>=6 (from bleach[css]<7,>=6->wiki)
  Using cached bleach-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (30 kB)
Collecting django-mptt<0.16,>=0.13 (from wiki)
  Using cached django_mptt-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting django-nyt>=1.2.2 (from wiki)
  Using cached django_nyt-1.3-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting django-sekizai>=0.10 (from wiki)
  Using cached django_sekizai-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: django<4.3,>=3.2 in c:\python\wiki-env\lib\site-packages (from wiki) (4.2.6)
Collecting markdown<3.5,>=3.4 (from wiki)
  Using cached Markdown-3.4.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Collecting pillow (from wiki)
  Using cached Pillow-10.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.6 kB)
Collecting sorl-thumbnail<13,>=12.8 (from wiki)
  Using cached sorl_thumbnail-12.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from bleach<7,>=6->bleach[css]<7,>=6->wiki)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting webencodings (from bleach<7,>=6->bleach[css]<7,>=6->wiki)
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting tinycss2<1.3,>=1.1.0 (from bleach[css]<7,>=6->wiki)
  Using cached tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.6.0 in c:\python\wiki-env\lib\site-packages (from django<4.3,>=3.2->wiki) (3.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.3.1 in c:\python\wiki-env\lib\site-packages (from django<4.3,>=3.2->wiki) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\python\wiki-env\lib\site-packages (from django<4.3,>=3.2->wiki) (2023.3)
Collecting django-js-asset (from django-mptt<0.16,>=0.13->wiki)
  Using cached django_js_asset-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting django-classy-tags>=3.0 (from django-sekizai>=0.10->wiki)
  Using cached django_classy_tags-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=4.4 (from markdown<3.5,>=3.4->wiki)
  Using cached importlib_metadata-6.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4 in c:\python\wiki-env\lib\site-packages (from asgiref<4,>=3.6.0->django<4.3,>=3.2->wiki) (4.8.0)
Collecting zipp>=0.5 (from importlib-metadata>=4.4->markdown<3.5,>=3.4->wiki)
  Using cached zipp-3.17.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Using cached bleach-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Using cached django_mptt-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
Using cached Markdown-3.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Using cached sorl_thumbnail-12.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Using cached Pillow-10.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.6 MB)
Using cached django_classy_tags-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Using cached importlib_metadata-6.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Using cached django_js_asset-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Using cached zipp-3.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: wiki
  Building editable for wiki (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for wiki: filename=wiki-0.10-py3-none-any.whl size=17935 sha256=e5521f921922ea2e39f377fe0aadbeb51d96ecab3841ce165f75571620a97b7b
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ianpi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-5qdcnglr\wheels\d4\df\f4\3f4d47e234cf00f7427beeea9ce4428059385db035bf4c57ce
Successfully built wiki
Installing collected packages: webencodings, zipp, tinycss2, sorl-thumbnail, six, pillow, importlib-metadata, bleach, markdown, django-nyt, django-js-asset, django-classy-tags, django-sekizai, django-mptt, wiki
Successfully installed bleach-6.1.0 django-classy-tags-4.1.0 django-js-asset-2.1.0 django-mptt-0.15.0 django-nyt-1.3 django-sekizai-4.1.0 importlib-metadata-6.8.0 markdown-3.4.4 pillow-10.1.0 six-1.16.0 sorl-thumbnail-12.10.0 tinycss2-1.2.1 webencodings-0.5.1 wiki-0.10 zipp-3.17.0

(wiki-env) C:\python>cd wiki-env\src\wiki\testproject
```

There's no database at this point, although the readme implies that there should be a pre-populated one.  Trying to start up a server fails here with a missing table error, so I thought using the django migrate utility might be a good next step.

```
(wiki-env) C:\python\wiki-env\src\wiki\testproject>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_nyt, sessions, sites, thumbnail, wiki, wiki_attachments, wiki_images, wiki_notifications
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0001_initial... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0002_notification_settings... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0003_subscription... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0004_notification_subscription... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0005__v_0_9_2... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0006_auto_20141229_1630... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0007_add_modified_and_default_settings... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0008_auto_20161023_1641... OK
  Applying django_nyt.0009_alter_notification_subscription_and_more... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
  Applying thumbnail.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wiki.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wiki.0002_urlpath_moved_to... OK
  Applying wiki.0003_mptt_upgrade... OK
  Applying wiki_attachments.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wiki_attachments.0002_auto_20151118_1816... OK
  Applying wiki_images.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wiki_images.0002_auto_20151118_1811... OK
  Applying wiki_notifications.0001_initial... OK
  Applying wiki_notifications.0002_auto_20151118_1811... OK
```

Now the server starts up ok.

```
(wiki-env) C:\python\wiki-env\src\wiki\testproject>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 26, 2023 - 21:39:40
Django version 4.2.6, using settings 'testproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

[image: missing root article]
But I can't log in using admin/admin per the readme.  I've tried using `manage.py createsuperuser` to make a user and I've tried using the sign up function, but none of the user ids seem to allow me to sign in.  I just keep getting one or other of the login pages.  So I'm stuck.

Unless I can get the project working and create an article with a table in it, I can't see if the change I want to make works and I can't make a test case for it and submit a proper pull request.

I feel like the crux of this issue is the lack of the pre-populated database which is noted in the readme.  Can anyone suggest what I might have done wrong or an avenue to investigate?